# Thinkpad Yoga460: Stylus Buttons Stopped Working

Tags: kubuntu, thinkpad, wacom, stylus

I just freshly installed Kubuntu 23.04 on my ThinkPad.
The stylus tip (left click) worked out of the box, so did the upper button (middle click).
I took a look in the graphic tablets settings to see, if can get the lower button to work, too (right click).

The mapping of the buttons in the setting dialogue seemed to be not quite correct (right click on the upper button). I changed the settings - and now everything but the tip is dead. :\ And it stayed that way even after hitting reset in the dialogue and rebooting.

I'm not a terminal person but it appears to me that the system still recognizes the buttons?^^

```
    ill66@ThinkPad ~ $ xsetwacom --get "Wacom Pen and multitouch sensor Pen stylus" Button 3
button +2 
ill66@ThinkPad ~ $ xsetwacom --get "Wacom Pen and multitouch sensor Pen stylus" Button 2
button +3 
ill66@ThinkPad ~ $ xsetwacom --get "Wacom Pen and multitouch sensor Pen stylus" Button 1
button +1
```

Tried to reassign them via --set but to no effect...